# Why is & 0xFFFF needed when checking if caps lock on

Tags: c#, .net, capslock

I'm trying to check if CAPS LOCK is on.
I have seen the following line and I was wondering why is the AND with 0xFFFF needed since AND with 0xFFFF will return exactly the same number. I have read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) that in order to check if the CAPS LOCK is toggled, you need to check the lower-order bit hence it should be AND with 1. So, why 0xFFFF?

```
bool CapsLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the `GetKeyState` is in fact [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate), then the `0xffff` is completely pointless. If it's a custom wrapper returning an `int`, it may have a purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I aggree with GSerg that it is not needed to be used. But normally the use of and bitwise operator is to get portion of the value.

for instance:

```
0x11ffff
0xffff 
--------- AND
0xffff
```

You can use [this online bitwise calculator](https://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/?data_type=16&number1=0x11ffff&number2=0xffff&operator=AND) to understand how it works.